# How can I reuse JQuery dynamic tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a function to add images to a site. These go into a DIV, using .html()
After that's done I need those same images to show an effect on hover, but nothing happens when I hover them.
If I type the same code I use in the .html() function, same class, etc, hover works.

After lots of attempts, I narrowed my problem to this sample.
Turns out the problem is how the container DIV exposes the code added through .html() ... and my hover functions can't find the dynamically added tags.

Here's my sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Problems</title>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="TXToldone">This line was already here</p>
<div id="DIVnewone"></div>
<script>

function createnewone(){
   $txthtml="<p id=\"TXTnewone\">And this one got added dynamically</p>";
   $("#DIVnewone").html($txthtml);
};
$(document).ready(function() {
   createnewone();
}); 
$("*").on("click", function(){
   alert( $(this).attr("id") );
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Notes:**
 - This is just a raw example of my real problem. This is not what I'm
   actually trying to accomplish, but solving this one would make me
   solve the real one ;)
 - The first two functions are from the actual code ... after document
   is ready I load the pics and recursively add the html required to
   each DIV ...
 - Third function is just so you guys can see my problem ... It should
   be showing an alert with the ID of the element you click on (and it
   does for the 1st paragraph) ... but check what happens when you click
   the second one ... you don't see the ID for that paragraph but the ID
   for the container DIV instead!
 - (yes, it also gives alerts for the other parents, up to the document,
   but hey, it's just an example)
 - If I manually add the paragraph to that same DIV, the "static"
   paragraph shows its ID when clicked on, but the "dynamic" one still
   shows the DIV ID.

Please, advise?
(also, I need the script to stay at the bottom of my code, so it can "see" all the pics)

EDIT so my point is clearer: I need a way to add content to a DIV so other functions see the new code.

How would you guys replace this line so the sample code works as intended?

```
$("#DIVnewone").html($txthtml);
```

Comment: The main point is: when you attach the events (`on()`), that element is not in the DOM yet. So the event won't be attached on it. You have to either attach the event again to the added element, or use event delegation (`delegate`, or [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) in newer jQuery, or `live` which is deprecated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried appending the new element to the div rather than setting it via html(), though I believe .html() should work as well.

```
function createnewone(){
   $txthtml="<p id=\"TXTnewone\">And this one got added dynamically</p>";
   $("#DIVnewone").append($txthtml);
};
```

then you can use the below ON function (1.7+) to do what you need it to do when you have the mouse over the selector ('#TXTnewone'). Note that the below will need to go into the "`$(document).ready(function() { ...here... }`" function, this is to ensure the "body" tag has been loaded when assigning the on event to it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    createnewone();
    $("body").on(
        {
              mouseenter: function () { $(this).css("color","red"); }
            , mouseleave: function () { $(this).css("color","black"); }
        }
        , "#TXTnewone"
    );
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLhUS/2/) of the above working.

Comment: Hmm ... you really seem to be right.
Playing around with your fiddle, I'm getting closer to what I need.
Yes, html() works aswell in your example ... the key to your post seems to be dynamically changing the CSS.
I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function.

or [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), after jQuery version 1.7

> **Description** 
> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, *now and in the future.*

Comment: Most likely my fault, by I can´t see it.
If I'm reading correctly, LIVE / ON will subscribe an element to an event ... but that doesn´t apply to the text I add through HTML() ...
Maybe if you explain more?

Comment: Isn't your newly-added text part of a newly-added element?  Just make that element part of the selector you use in the live function.

Comment: The container DIV is already there (as shown in the example), and what I do is set its HTML() to a new string ... a centered image with an anchor ... and my hover function looks for every anchor with a specific CLASS or ID ... but the new lines seem no a) not share the others' namespace b) not share it others' CLASS name (and no it's not a typo)

I edited the originl question so its easier to see what I'm looking for: html() adds the text but new text isn't behaving as regular text would have.

Answer (score 0):

Place your hover functions inside the event call that adds the dynamic content. Your hover functions are being evaluated before the content is added and aren't re-evaluated after, causing them to be `undefined`.

**EDIT**
Robert Harvey's answer is much better than this, but the idea is the same.